# ENtering Value on InputBox in AutoCAD using Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I am working on a code that opens AutoCAD and activates the input box and enters a value and then enters the value. The problem with my code is that it opens autoCad and runs the code for inputBox but then creates a different inputBox in excel. I want my code to work only in AutoCAD but using excel. Here is my code:

```
Sub Access_ACad()
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim ans As String
Dim MyApp As Object
Dim MyDwg As AcadDocument
Dim ShellDraft As String
On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
Set MyApp = GetObject(, "Autocad.Application")
ERRORHANDLER:
If Err.Description <> "" Then
Err.Clear
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
End If

MyApp.Visible = True
Set MyDwg = MyApp.ActiveDocument
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = MyDwg.Name
ShellDraft = "Z:\USERS\KweziM\PROJECT S\Project.dvb"

MyApp.LoadDVB (ShellDraft)

MyApp.RunMacro "FCI"

myValue = InputBox("1 = FCI" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = ECI", "Model", 1)
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that the two inputbox prompts which you are looking at are from different owning applications i.e. FCI Macro has an inputbox (comes from ACAD) and the second inputbox prompt you are getting is from the code you've posted above which is owned by Excel.

Comment: yes that's what happens, how can i fix this

Comment: If that is what is happening then I'd think that this line in Excel (above code) is redundant. `myValue = InputBox("1 = FCI" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = ECI", "Model", 1)` Comment it out and check your code again.

Comment: thing is i want the code to open the inputbox on AutoCad and select "1" as the answer and then "enter" the value automatically, i don't know if I am making sense. So I need a syntax that will link the  `myValue` line to the inputBox on AutoCad not excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need to do based on our exchange above.

1. Remove code line(s) which are in Excel i.e. code which you have posted here.

`myValue = InputBox("1 = FCI" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = ECI", "Model", 1)
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"`

2. Open AutoCAD VB project's DVB file and macro named "FCI". Insert the line

`myValue = InputBox("1 = FCI" & vbCrLf & _
           "2 = ECI", "Model", 1)`
where appropriate. You don't need SendKeys syntax since you will get prompt through AutoCAD itself. Use `myValue` as you need in the code further.